# How to open another device in a linux module?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, driver, device

For example , I have a '/dev/a' as a cdev.
Now I want to write a module 'b' and before 'b' is registered , I need to send a message to 'a' so that 'a' will be started.
I used to do it by ioctl() in an application, but now I want to do it in module 'b'.
open() can't be used in the module, so how can I open 'a' in module 'b'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open this way

```
struct file* test;
test = filp_open("/dev/targetDevice",O_RDWR,0);
```

Now in call ioctl

```
test->f_op->unlocked_ioctl(test,IOCTL_MACRO,params);
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a device you should use open system call in linux and check the list of available devices for example `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyS0` etc. and open it and you will get a descriptor to write and read on to the device is you open a device to communicate.

```
int fd;
fd=open(“/dev/ttyUSB0”, O_RDWR);
```

To know the further details follow this [link](http://www.firmcodes.com/lower-level-file-handling-in-linux/).